# Activating Popup in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I've got a bunch of conference session information formatted as a listview widget within a jQuery Mobile app. At the moment I have a paragraph within each li that contains the much longer session description and I've styled it to be display:none. I've wrapped the entire li in a link that goes nowhere at the moment. I'm looking for help on how to programmatically open the hidden paragraph as a popup widget when someone clicks on the li. Normally I believe popup activation links are related to a div's unique id, which my many session descriptions do not currently have. And my content is with-in the href element, not separate from it. Could someone suggest a wise approach to popping up this hidden paragraph? I'm hoping to avoid having to create individual ids for each description, and maybe even avoid having to wrap the paragraph in a special div for the popup. Here's my current li code...

```
<li class="preconference_1-day"><a href="#">
<h3>Conflict Management and Peacebuilding as a Classroom Management Tool</h3>
<p> Presented by <strong>Some University</strong></p>
<p>Location: McPherson Lab, Room 1035</p>
<p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>9:00 AM</strong></p>
<p style="display:none">Description: Participants will be introduced to a...</p></a>
</li>
```

I'm using jquery-2.2.4 and jquery.mobile-1.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to use the data attribute to store the extra info

**e.g**   `<li data-extra="Description: The second set..." class="preconference_1-day">`

**Code**

```
//The list item click function
$("#listview > li").on("click", function() {
//Get whats in the data attribute from item clicked
var extra = $(this).attr("data-extra");
//Empty whats inside the popup, append data, and open the popup
$("#mypopup").empty().append("<p>"+extra+"</p>").popup("open");
});
```

[The Popup Widget and all its options](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/)

[About the data-* attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xbj9xabh/)**

Comment: Nice on Tasos! OP could still use a hidden div with your method, especially if html tags within the popup content is desired: http://jsfiddle.net/xbj9xabh/1/

Comment: @ezanker -- yeah i know, but a bit more data in the DOM though

Comment: Thanks for the code example. While I was initially more attracted to ezanker's example (less change in my li code for multiple items),  I ran into some perplexing challenges related to the mobile page create function. Not sure if it was my IDE preview mode or what. In any case, based on your examples I'm over the hurdle now. I appreciate the help!